# PowerEdge R710 Optimise Power Consumption

Tags: power-supply, virtualization, vmware

Few days ago I've purchased a certified refurbished Dell poweredge R710 from amazon with following specs :

> Processors: 2 x 2.80Ghz X5660 Hex Core Memory: 16 x 8GB PC3-10600R Hard Drives: 6 x 2TB x 7.2K SATA 3.5" Drive Bays: 6 hotswap 3.5" Power Supplies: 2 x DELL 870W RAID Controller: PERC H700 Network Interface: x Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet Video Card: ATI Technologies Inc ES1000 Optical Drive: DVD-ROM Included Remote Access Controller: iDRAC Enterprise

I've purchased this server for virtualization purposes (to install Vmware ESXi) in a home lab, however i stupidly forgotten to take in consideration the very basic electricity bill factor, the server runs at 1740 Watt

> (2PSU= 2*870Watt = 1740 Watt) in my country we are charged at a 0.8$/KWh rate (What a government haa :/ !) and hence we are speaking about 1036$ monthly bill for a 24*7 operation (1295 KWh * 0.8), if i manage to run it on a single PSU and do best effort keeping it idle (powering on VMs only when needed) we are speaking about 297$ (500 Watt per hour and that would 372KWh * 0.8) which is more than my monthly income Smiley Sad !

anyone knows if this server can be optimized to operate on 200Watt, i think this is absolutely impossible but thought giving it a try.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Have you measured the power that is actually used by the server, under load and idle? An 870 Watt-rated PSU does not mean it will constantly use 870 Watts at all times.

Comment: You shouldn’t purchase a server if you want to save power. There is far more redundancy and higher end parts than needed for a home lab. Go in to the BIOS where you will find power optimization settings. But be warned it can and probably will cause performance or reliability issues.

Comment: Nevertheless, modern servers do not usually run at maximum power the whole time; the BIOS setup screen and/or the BMC (iDRAC) will have settings for automatic scaling. I don't know how old R710 is, but 200W during light load should be very possible.

Comment: Having a r710 in a Homelab I can confirm that it can idle at around 100w (one CPU, 1 HDD), but more realistic it will be around 120w for one cpu and around 150w with 2 cpus, and can go up to more than 200w depending on cpu type + load and additional hardware.